# Vuejs - pass slot to nested child

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a modal component that looks like this

```
//modal component
<template>
   <slot></slot>
   <slot name='buttons'></slot>
</template>
```

I want to use it as a wizard

```
//wizard component
<template>
   <modal>
      <step1-state v-if='step === 1'/>
      <step2-state v-if='step === 2'/>
   </modal>
</template>
```

Is there a way that step1,step2,etc consume `buttons` slot?

This does not seem to work

```
//step1-state component
<template>
   <div>
       <span>Does it work?</span>
       <div slot='buttons'>
          <button>yes</button>
          <button>no</button>
       </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Why do that when you could just have your `step1-state` and `step2-state` components use the `modal` directly and then just use a `div` or something as the wrapper in `wizard`?

Comment: @lamelemon This is what I ended up doing, but the question still stands. In my opinion this is possible use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found that this is not possible by default. 
I was able to achieve this using custom render functions.

`child-slot` component - this one needs to be placed inside parent slot content, it enables you to format content of child component. You can add more than one `child-slot` to mix it with parent content. It needs to define `ref` attribute with distinct value.

`use-slot` component - this one is used to tell what content should be passed to parent as `child-slot` content. Content will be placed inside `span` element.
It needs `named` and `container` attributes.

`named` - name of slot to place content in

`container` - `ref` value of `child-slot`

`use-slot` will automatically find first parent slot named by `named` attribute regardless of child depth

> child-slot

```
<script>
    export default {
        render(createElement) {
            return createElement('span', {}, this.content);
        },
        data() {
            return {
                nodesToRender: {}
            }
        },
        computed: {
            content() {
                var result = [];
                for (var node in this.nodesToRender) {
                    result = result.concat(this.nodesToRender[node] || []);
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

> use-slot

```
<script>
    export default {
        abstract: true,
        props: {
            named: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            container: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        render() {
            var parent = this.findParentOfSlot();
            var content = this.$slots.default;
            var self = this;
            this.$parent.$nextTick(function () {
                if (parent && parent.$refs && parent.$refs[self.container], parent.$refs[self.container].nodesToRender) {
                    Vue.set(parent.$refs[self.container].nodesToRender, self.$vnode.tag, content);
                }
            });
        },
        methods: {
            findParentOfSlot() {
                var parent = this.$parent;
                while (parent) {
                    if (parent.$slots && parent.$slots[this.named]) {
                        return parent.$parent;
                    }
                    parent = parent.$parent;
                }
                return parent;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Couold you give a full example of this in codepen?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible currently and doesn't make too much sense because it becomes complicated and hard to read. Imagine looking at such nested slot code after 3 months of writing it. If both your step components require this `buttons` slot then write it as a sibling near them and send props whenever you have changes from this `buttons` slot

By the way, there seems to be a wizard component out there https://github.com/cristijora/vue-form-wizard , accidentally written by myself ))